# Multiple Spring Batch jobs writing to same flat file

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have several different Spring Batch jobs that need to write to the same flat file.  The order of the data written out in the flat file does not matter.  These batch jobs may run at the same time.

Would the FlatFileItemWriter be appropriate?  My concern is if more than one job attempts to write to the flat file at the same time, the data could get commingled.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.html), it is not thread-safe.  So, if you have multiple threads writing to the same file, you'll have to implement your own locking mechanism.

Comment: I had read that, but assumed it meant you would not want multiple threads sharing the same FlatFileItemWriter object.  I will have multiple FlatFileItemWriter objects, each used by a single thread.  They will just all be using the same flat file.

Comment: Still have multiple threads using the same BufferedWriter, which will cause problems.  Or, you have multiple threads trying to access the same resource on the file system, which could lead to even weirder problems.  You want to lock the file for each of the different threads to write to it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

As @dardo wrote `FlatFileItemWriter` is not thread-safe so you can't write to the same file using multiple threads.
 A different solution than implements a custom locking mechanism might be to write to different files and create a new final step which job is to concatenate all previously created files. You can reuse your original jobs (to create file pieces as steps) wrapping them aroud a [`JobStep`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html)

Answer (score 0):

you could simply create a wrapper with a synchronized write method. Something like this:

```
public class SynchronizedWrapperWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T>, ItemStream {

  private ItemWriter<T> itemWriter;
  private boolean isStream = false;

  /**
   * setzen des ItemWriter.
   */
  public void setItemWriter(ItemWriter<T> itemWriter) {
    this.itemWriter = itemWriter;
    if (itemWriter instanceof ItemStream) {
      isStream = true;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    if (isStream) {
      ((ItemStream) itemWriter).close();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
    if (isStream) {
      ((ItemStream) itemWriter).open(new ExecutionContext());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
    itemWriter.write(items);
  }
}
```